# Select next available SKU in firebird table

Tags: sql, firebird, gaps-and-islands, firebird2.5

I have a table with unique SKU's

Table name "SKU"

| ID |
| --- |
| A100 |
| A101 |
| A102 |
| A109 |
| A110 |
| B100 |
| B101 |
| B105 |

In a query, I get the first two digits "A1" e.g. and I need to find the first "free" or avaiblable sku to use.

I'm currently using the next query, which returns the correct result but it's very slow so I would need a faster query if it's possible.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW NEXT_SKU(
    NEXTSKU)
AS
with T2 as (
        select CAST(substring(SKU.ID from 2 for 3) AS INTEGER) CODE
        from SKU
        WHERE SKU.ID LIKE ('A1' || '%')
        )


select

MIN(CAST(substring(T1.ID from 2 for 3) AS INTEGER) +1) as NEXTSKU

FROM SKU AS T1

LEFT JOIN T2 ON CAST(substring(T1.ID from 2 for 3) AS INTEGER)+1 = T2.CODE


WHERE
    T1.ID LIKE ('A1' || '%')
    AND T2.CODE IS NULL
;
```

I'm using firebird 2.5.

Comment: Can you move to FB3 and use window functions?  Something like `LEAD(CODE, 1, CODE + 2) OVER (ORDER BY CODE ASC) - CODE AS NEXT_SKU_DELTA`, finding the MINimum CODE WHERE NEXT_SKU_DELTA > 1 ?

Comment: `to find the first "free" or avaiblable sku` - what does "free" mean, in specific databae terms ??? go http://dbfiddle.uk and make a sample tables with sample data and the ourtput you want. Meanwhile it seems you need a query like `select first(1) id from SKU where id STARTING WITH 'A1' order by 1`